# JavaScript using window.onload multiple times

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a Hangman game that uses canvas and it has a reset button.
The `startGame()` function call is inside a `window.onload` for the first time but when I press the reset button, the event listener is calling `startGame` to reset everything, this time without `window.onload` and that causes problems with the canvas.I was able to get around it by calling `location.reload()` rather then `startGame` when the reset button is clicked.
Here is some code from the first level (global scope) to help you get into the business:

```
const startGame = async () => {
  const puzzle = await getPuzzle('2')
  game = new Hangman(puzzle, 10)
  clearCanvas()
  render()
}

const reset = () => {
  location.reload();
}

document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener('click', reset)
```

The last lines of the code are:

```
window.onload = () => {
  startGame()
}
```

I tried to place `window.onload` inside the `startGame` function and in other places such as the file that contains the canvas related functions and it caused all kind of issues.
Now I know that onload happens only once so those attempts didn't stood a chance.
The code above gets the job done but it feels wrong. Is there another way to deal with this issue? Is my way ok?

Comment: Why does it feel wrong?

Comment: the `window.onload` event is fired when the window is loaded, as the name tries to imply. thus the only way to trigger it is to reload it, as you are already doing. if you do not want to run your initialization code when the window is loaded, you should put it somewhere else.